# Spring JSP file upload with or without submitting to server

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

The question is regarding design of my application (spring mvc) and I am not sure I am doing it right. I need to give user upload file option and then parse the uploaded file, validate and show data in JSP. After displaying data if user choose to submit it only then I put data in DB.

What I have done is when user upload file then process it and store information in DB, and then show with pagination in JSP. If users doesn't submit data then I clean up such data next day. Problem I see is so many DB calls and unnecessary data in my DB.

I have read that associate upload request with session and store in memory but apprehensive how will it handle if hundred of user tries to upload nearly the same time.

Please advise is this approach right design and performance wise / or what is the right way to handle such requirement.

Comment: Can the user postponed the decision on the data to later data.

Comment: Submiting the data and validation happens concurrently. If you are saying that showing and validating can be different call; then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting question, but IMHO the answer depends on :

- the size of the uploaded files
- the number of concurrent sessions
- the capacity of the server

The only thing that seems clear to me is that data should not go into definitive tables in database before validation, unless there is a special field in it saying it is still not validated and should not be used. But anyway, it would add unnecessary complexity.

That being said, you have to persist some session related data across different requests for a *short* period of time. So depending of the parameters cited at the beginning or the post, you can use :

- a cookie if data is small (about 1 kbyte since cookie max capacity is 4 kbytes)
- object(s) in session if data is small regarding the available memory and few concurrent sessions
- form data in eventually hidden fields is data structure is simple - it is an option to considere if you display all (or almost all) of data to user for validation with possibility to modify some fields
- a file in a folder on server , with only the name of file in session. It is a nice solution, but you have to implement cleaning in a session listener if the session is closed without the user has validated its data, and a catch all cleaning at server restart in case of abnormal stop of the application.